# How to convert any human readable date to unix timestamp

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, unix-timestamp

I have a date like this 01/20/2013 and trying to get the unix timestamp for this date. I have searched a lot and found out that how to convert present date into unix timestamp but didn't find my solution.

here is my code what i'm doing.

```
NSDate *date = mydate;     //myDate is the date like 01/20/2013

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[ NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy"];

NSString *timestamp = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@",timestamp);
```

I'm getting null as timestamp value in my console.

Comment: format should be "MM/dd/yyyy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS provides [-(NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSince1970](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for NSDate objects which returns the number of seconds since 00:00:00 GMT January 1, 1970. NSTimeInterval is a double floating point type so you get the seconds and fractions of a second.

```
time_t unixTime = (time_t) [your_date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Here time_t is usually a signed 32-bit integer type (long or int).

Comment: I tried like this but it's crashing.

NSDate *date = [[appDelegate.configFileArray objectAtIndex:3] valueForKey:@"1"];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
time_t unixTime = (time_t) [date timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"%ld",unixTime);

Comment: No it should not crash. I have checked this. Ex:  time_t unixTime = (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSLog(@"unixtime : %li",unixTime); It returns me unixtime : 1367326434

Comment: I think you are passing wrong date. Please check it once.

Comment: NSDate *date = [[appDelegate.configFileArray objectAtIndex:3] valueForKey:@"1"]; NSLog(@"%@",date);  when i do this then in my log m getting "01/20/2013". is this wrong date to pass.

Comment: What is the date can you tell in your console ?

Comment: in my console i'm getting like this "01/20/2013".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29189/discussion-between-zac24-and-nishant-tyagi)

Answer (score 1):

you can get it with

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSince1970
```

**UPDATE:**

**For Example in `int` ...**

```
int unixtimestamp = [mydate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

**And other Example in `NSTimeInterval`**

```
NSTimeInterval ti = [mydate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: this will convert the present date to unix timestamp.. how can i provide my own date..?

Comment: you have string Date now??

Comment: @Zac24 i update answer dear see that... if you have string date then use my method for convert that String date to NSDate...

Comment: @Zac24 just pass that date in that like NSDate *date = [[appDelegate.configFileArray objectAtIndex:3] valueForKey:@"1"];int unixDateInt = [date timeIntervalSince1970];

Comment: i tried that but it crashing. i think some problem with date i'm passing as Nishant said above but i dont know what's the problem n how to fix it.

Comment: first check that you get value in [[appDelegate.configFileArray objectAtIndex:3] valueForKey:@"1"]??

Comment: @Zac24 its crashed when you date variable have no value and its `nil`... that is the reason i am sure..

Comment: ya i logged it and in my console m getting this "01/20/2013".

Comment: now i use this code.. `int unixtimestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSLog(@"\n\n =>>> Int==>> %d",unixtimestamp);` and it logs **=>>> Int==>> 1367327533**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29191/discussion-between-zac24-and-paras-joshi)